# How to clone or export a forum thread?

Tags: nodes, backups

I am wondering what is the best way to somehow clone/export/duplicate a single forum thread?

Comment: Are you using the stock forum module, or one of the others?

Comment: did u try http://drupal.org/project/bundle_copy